# Disable The Control:

Tags: asp.net

Hai Friends.,

Im doing a project on Airline Reservation.In my project i have a radiobox with two items Oneway and Round trip. If i select anyone of the radiobtn the corresponding dropdownlist box should be disabled.,How can i do it?What is the code to disable the controls which are not necessary?

Thankls in Advance For Those Who Answer's me........

,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/ajube)

```
<script>
function DisableDropDown(elem, elem2)
{
    var elementDropDown = document.getElementById ( elem );
    var elementDropDown2 = document.getElementById ( elem2 );
    elementDropDown.disabled = true;
    elementDropDown2.disabled = false;
}
</script>
<input type="radio" onclick="DisableDropDown('sel1','sel2');" name="radioGroup" id="rdBtn1" />

<select id="sel1">
<option>test</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="radio" onclick="DisableDropDown('sel2','sel1');" name="radioGroup" id="rdBtn2" />

<select id="sel2">
<option>test</option>
</select>
```